# RSpec fails to run --bisect, with error: undefined method `run' for #<RSpec::Core::Bisect::Server>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, drb

I am currently in the process of upgrading a fairly large Rails application from Rails 3 --> Rails 4 (or maybe 5).

I am currently at a point where I have a `Rails v4.0.13` application, running on `Ruby v2.1.5`. The test suite is running on `RSpec v3.5.2`, and is **green** (woohoo!), but unfortunately with some intermittent failures.

I'd ideally like to track down the cause of these failures before upgrading further, using [rspec --bisect](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/command-line/bisect).

However, when I run `rspec --bisect` (with or without other arguments), I get the following error:

```
Bisect started using options: ""
Running suite to find failures...

Bisect failed! Failed to get results from the spec run. Spec run output:

(druby://127.0.0.1:33858) /home/tom/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/drb/drb.rb:1588:in `perform_without_block': undefined method `run' for #<RSpec::Core::Bisect::Server:0x00000001e71430> (NoMethodError)
        from (druby://127.0.0.1:33858) /home/tom/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/drb/drb.rb:1548:in `perform'
        from (druby://127.0.0.1:33858) /home/tom/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/drb/drb.rb:1626:in `block (2 levels) in main_loop'
        from (druby://127.0.0.1:33858) /home/tom/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/drb/drb.rb:1622:in `loop'
        from (druby://127.0.0.1:33858) /home/tom/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/drb/drb.rb:1622:in `block in main_loop'
        from /home/tom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@<project-name>/gems/rspec-core-3.5.2/lib/rspec/core/drb.rb:23:in `run'
        from /home/tom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@<project-name>/gems/rspec-core-3.5.2/lib/rspec/core/invocations.rb:19:in `call'
        from /home/tom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@<project-name>/gems/rspec-core-3.5.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'
        from /home/tom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@<project-name>/gems/rspec-core-3.5.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:45:in `invoke'
        from /home/tom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@<project-name>/gems/rspec-core-3.5.2/exe/rspec:4:in `<main>'
```

Has anyone got a clue what could be causing this, or how I may be able to track down the cause?

Some things I've tried so far, to no avail:

- Downgrade rspec to a lower version (`>= 3.3.0`, since that's when `--bisect` was added).
- Upgrade ruby to a higher version (namely `2.3.1`). (This causes a few test failures which I'm yet to resolve, but still doesn't affect this `--bisect` issue).
- Clean up the system with `rvm gemset empty <project_name>; gem install bunder; bundle`, to purge all the pre-upgrade library code that was lying around.

It's also worth noting that I have *other* Rails projects on this computer, for which running `--bisect` works just fine - so I don't think this can be a system library compatibility issue. I guess it must be something to do with the project configuration -- but *what?!* (I can't even see an application back-trace for clues??)

**Edit:** Without finding a resolution to this yet, I've continued upgrading the application. It is now running `Rails v4.2.7` and `Ruby v2.3.1`, with all specs passing (but still with some ordering issue). The error message when running `rspec --bisect` remains unchanged.

Comment: DRb seems like a distraction. What happens when you run rspec --bisect without --drb?

Comment: I didn't include the `--drb` option; this behaviour seems to be a consequence of just using `--bisect` (?). I have also tried using the option [`--no-drb`](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/350c21b6f66a54267ff615ed16604e017122e6be/spec/rspec/core/configuration_options_spec.rb#L3160), but again get an identical console output.

Comment: See also, [this pull request](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/pull/2223) - although I'm not sure how relevant it is, since I've tried using older versions of rspec too.

Comment: Oops, you're correct — --bisect uses DRb.

Comment: This is a long shot, but do you happen to have a `.rspec` file? I was able to recreate a similar error on an empty rails project with adding spork it to. The spork documentation suggests adding `--drb` straight to `.rspec` file. When I  removed that option, the --bisect started to work again.

Comment: @LauraPaakkinen Yes!! I'd forgotten that a `.rspec` file even exists - and I guess my predecessor must have indeed been using `spork` when this project was first built. I still have no idea why including that flag causes such a cryptic failure, but removing it was all I needed to do. If you'd like to submit this as an answer, I'll award the bounty :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a long shot, but do you happen to have a .rspec file?

I was able to recreate a similar error on an empty rails project with adding spork it to. For some reason running `rspec --bisect --drb` provokes this issue.

The spork documentation suggests adding `--drb` straight to .rspec file. So make sure that it has been removed and when you run just `rspec --bisect` it should work.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this error and fixed it with bypassing spring and spring-commands-rspec.

Do not use `bin/rspec --bisect`, try:

```
# Stop spring
bin/spring stop

# Ensure rspec isn't using spring
bundle exec rspec --bisect
```